# JSON CONTAINS not producing correct result with one character search

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a JSON column and I'm trying to do search on this column by using CONTAINS function.

```
Table1
JSON_COL
{
"MarketInfo":
"ABCDEFGHE"{
"OriginalData": "I"
}
}

Select * from table1 where CONTAINS(JSON_COOL, "I INPATH('/MarketInfo/ABCDEFGHE/OriginalData)')>0) --> gives me no result
```

But when I change the data as below.

```
JSON_COL
{
"MarketInfo":
"ABCDEFGHE"{
"OriginalData": "II"
}
}
Select * from table1 where CONTAINS(JSON_COOL, "II INPATH('/MarketInfo/ABCDEFGHE/OriginalData)')>0) --> This gives me result
```

Basically changing "I" to "II". Then it is working fine.

Can you let me know what is the issue with first query.

Comment: First, the example is neither using a valid JSON document, nor the SQL is valid. Second, if you have JSON documents, use json_textcontains instead of contains. And from the doc, it seems INPATH is for XML not JSON (though it seems to work in some cases)

Comment: Provided is an example, can't paste all the JSON text here for security purpose. Yeah, I can use json_textcontains but my question is when I'm searching with 'II' the same query is working and when I search with 'I' why I'm getting an error.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? I did some tests and both json_textcontains and contains work.

Comment: I'm using 12c oracle database

Comment: I checked in my machine by using JSON_TEXTCONTAINS and JSON_VALUE as well functions when I search for 'I' the results are not produced. This is very STRANGE! but ture.

Comment: Can you please show the full SQL for creating the search index, as well as the SELECT?